# Exchange Web Service(EWS) : How to acces all users tasks folder in an organisation

Tags: python, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I need to access the tasks folder of all the users of O365 in my organisation. For that, I am using Exchanged Web Service(EWS). I was able to access my own tasks folder and the one that was shared with me but I need to access all of them.

I would need a way to force every account to share their tasks folder with me to accomplish what I want to do(I can't ask everyone in the organisation to do it themself, it would be to complicated since there is about 400 users).

Is there a permission that I can grant myself as an admin to avoid the shared folder thing or a script that I could run that would do this task for me?

Here's my code so far:

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, Account, Credentials, ServiceAccount, \
    EWSDateTime, EWSTimeZone, Configuration, NTLM, CalendarItem, Message, \
    Mailbox, Attendee, Q, ExtendedProperty, FileAttachment, ItemAttachment, \
    HTMLBody, Build, Version
import json

credentials = Credentials(username='admin@mycorp.local', password='password') 
config = Configuration(server='outlook.office365.com' , credentials=credentials)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='userINeedToAccess@mycorp.local', credentials=credentials, config=config,
    autodiscover=False, access_type=DELEGATE)


all_tasks = []
json_tasks = []
for t in account.tasks.all():
    all_tasks.append(t)


for t in all_tasks:
    data = {"Action" : t.subject, "actualWork": t.actual_work, "Project": t.billing_information, "Status": t.status, "Owner": t.owner, "isComplete": t.is_complete}
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    print(json_data)

print(account.tasks.total_count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect all email adresses, and you need your Exchange admin to grant sufficient permissions to these accounts from the account you're connecting with. Granting permissions can usually be done with a PowerShell script using the admin commands on the Exchange server.